# How do you pause and resume a while loop in Python. Can you help me with this Snake Game I have built using python-turtle?

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

I have built a snake game using python programming language and its turtle library.
Here you will find the link to my code, where I have also mentioned the help I need with it in Read Me file which I have kept really short and simple for you to go through it quickly.

[Snake Game](https://github.com/Ishan2608/Snake-Game)

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can't really pause a while loop and resume it at your will. But, what you can do is pause the while loop for some seconds, minutes, or hours. This can be done using the .sleep() method from the time library
Example:

```
import time
x = 1
while x == 1:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(5)
```